# order posts by `meta_key`, Does not display posts that does not have `meta_key`

Tags: plugins, wp-query, query-posts

I'm using this query orderby `meta_key` for show posts.
if one of the posts does not have `vip_row` meta, So not shown;
Is it possible that if one of the posts does not have `vip_row` meta to be displayed,But in the last row?

```
 $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'my_product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'my_product_cat',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => array($category->slug)
                )
            ),
            'meta_key' => 'vip_row',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all posts by using a `meta_query` that gets posts where the key either does or does not exist, and then order on meta key with a secondary order for posts with same value or no key:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_product'
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $category->slug )
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'vip_row',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'vip_row'
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
        'date' => 'ASC',
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```